# Is there anyway we can have an animated gif in the email's subject line?

Tags: html-email

or can we have a particular code to write in the **html** that can affect the subject line?

such as in the style ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animated icon in email subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095387/animated-icon-in-email-subject)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put an animated gif in the subject line, however, some email clients (iPhone, Android) will render some unicode entities as images.

This site has a listing of some - 
http://ecommerce-blog.nexternal.com/%E2%98%85-use-symbols-in-your-email-subject-lines-to-get-noticed-%E2%98%85/

However, you certainly will want to test this in many email clients to insure against adverse effects.

Answer (score 0):

Doubt it - but it ultimately depends on the email client implementation as HTML email doesn't seem to be well defined/standardized.

Based on sections 3.6.5, and 2.2.1 of [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822), the subject line is:

> referred to as [an] unstructured field body.  Semantically, unstructured
> field bodies are simply to be treated as a single line of characters
> with no further processing.

The message body (section 2.3), on the other hand, supports other MIME types:

> [RFC2045, RFC2046, RFC2048, RFC2049]
> that extend this standard to allow for different sorts of message
> bodies.